# How to place my text over the image in ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I am new to android ,i had 4 TextViews and 1 ImageView,i want to display 
image over 2 textview remaining textview display down to the image all view should be display scrollView [![i want like this with scrollview]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/beXVL.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="0.5">
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="@+id/textvats"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image2"
    android:src="@drawable/image2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textvat"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="pavan"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    />
</RelativeLayout >
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="pawan"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextViewandroid:id="@+id/textv"
style="@style/CodeFont"
android:layout_weight="0.45"
android:text="@string/Hello" />
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="#FF00F0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far..

Comment: my image was not uploading in stackoverflow

Comment: this is my sample screen                           http://i.stack.imgur.com/beXVL.png

Comment: hey please post your XML Code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this piece of code ..it has textviews over imageview
this will clear your doubt

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip">


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loginProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/postedOnTextView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/registerClickText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/registerClickText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/forgotClickText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/registerClickText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/forgotClickText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/registerClickText"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:inputType="textWebPassword|textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/registerClickText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:text="Login" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logoapp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emailEditText"
    android:text="Email"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/postedOnTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/registerClickText"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="83dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/loginProgressBar"
    android:text="New user?"
    android:textColor="#c3807e7f" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/forgotClickText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/loginProgressBar"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/loginProgressBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
    android:text="Forgot Password"
    android:textColor="#c3807e7f" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use this code in your  XML .
hope this will help you.

P.S. if you need scroll ability
add whole xml code inside scroll view tag

sample scroll view

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/dashboard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/school"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

your rest of the xml components


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: how to place my text over the image in scrollveiw